# Simple task for beginner (array with return)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return, average

Sorry for my english not the best yet.
I made a simple task i'm just learning the java yet, my question is how I can do it this task better?
The task is, made an array with not whole numbers, put these numbers to the array, and after this write it minimum, maximum, and average, with return method. I did it but I don't like it what a did.

How can I do it this task better? Or Where the return method have the for cycle? Or its impossible?

My code is:

```
public class program {

    public static  class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // write your code here
            double[] tömb;
            int max = 10;
            tömb = new double[max];
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                tömb[i] = i * 1.65223;
            }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                konvertáló(i);
                System.out.println("to whole number "+konvertáló(i));
            }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            double minimum=tömb[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
                if(minimum(i)<  minimum){
                    minimum=minimum(i);
                }

            }
            System.out.println("minimum value "+minimum);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            double avg=0;
            for (int i = 0; i <max ; i++) {
                avg+=avg(i);
            }
            System.out.println("az average value "+avg/max);

            double maximum=tömb[0];
            for (int i = 0; i <max ; i++) {
                if(maximum <maximum(i)){
                    maximum=maximum(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("maximum value "+maximum);
        }

        public static double konvertáló(double x) {

            return Math.round(x);
        }
        public static double minimum(double y) {


            return Math.round(y);
        }
        public static double avg(double y) {


            return Math.round(y);
        }

        public static double maximum(double y) {


            return Math.round(y);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: return method? where do you plan to return anything from or to? you are working with local variables.

Comment: I dont want to write so much in the main, my plan is that use the return methods for litle counting like avg,max,min (for,if, foreach, while, do, while..) its possible?

Comment: whether you want to write so much in the main or not makes no difference. Everything is in one class, you don't have instance members ... why do you think you need getters?

Comment: Hint: you can also use the `java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics` class to do all that calculation for you (despite you would not learn how to do it yourself with methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
                // write your code here
                double[] tomb;
                int max = 10;
                tomb = new double[max];
                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                        tomb[i] = i * 1.65223;
                }
                System.out.println("Minimum: " + getMin(tomb));
                System.out.println("Maximum: " + getMax(tomb));
                System.out.println("Average: " + getAverage(tomb));
        }

        private static double getMin(double[] tomb) {
                double min = tomb[0];
                for (double d:tomb) {
                        if (d < min) {
                                min = d;
                        }
                }
                return min;
        }

        private static double getMax(double[] tomb) {
                double max = tomb[0];
                for (double d:tomb) {
                        if (d > max) {
                                max = d;
                        }
                }
                return max;
        }
        private static double getAverage(double[] tomb) {
                double avg = 0;
                for (double d:tomb) {
                        avg+=d;
                }
                return avg/tomb.length;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks,that's what I was looking for.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

do it in one method. and there is a lot of similar question on stack overflow, someone will mark your question as duplicate. any way. check next code, it will print min, max, and avr

```
public static void max_min_avr(int[] numbers) {
    int maxValue = numbers[0];
    int minValue = numbers[0];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > maxValue)
            maxValue = numbers[i];
        if (numbers[i] < minValue)
            minValue = numbers[i];
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Max: " + maxValue);
    System.out.println("Min: " + minValue);
    System.out.println("AVR: " + sum + numbers[0] / numbers.length);
}
```

if you need return values. and do not want to write a lot in main. break code in methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(min(new double[]{3.0,4.0,5.0,7.0,9.0}));
    System.out.println(max(new double[]{3.0,4.0,5.0,7.0,9.0}));
    System.out.println(avr(new double[]{3.0,4.0,5.0,7.0,9.0}));
}


public static double max(double[]numbers){
    double maxValue = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > maxValue)
            maxValue = numbers[i];
    }

    return maxValue;
}

public static double min(double[] numbers){
    double minValue = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] < minValue)
            minValue = numbers[i];
    }
    return minValue;
}

public static double avr(double[] numbers){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    return sum / (double) numbers.length;
}
```

if you are familiar with stream. most short code would be next.

```
    List<Double> d = Arrays.asList(3.0,4.0,5.0,7.0,9.0);
    d.stream().max(Double::compare).ifPresent(System.out::println);
    d.stream().min(Double::compare).ifPresent(System.out::println);
    d.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x).average().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

put it in main method and you will have min, max, and avr in 4 lines of code.

Comment: who downvoted me?

Comment: This is easy, my question is another that I dont want to write so much in the main, my plan is that use the return methods for litle counting like avg,max,min (with like for,if, foreach, while, do, while..) its possible? and if yes how?

Comment: i have updated my answer, chek it out